# Using injected values

Tags: macros, metaprogramming, elixir

I'm trying to use injected values like:

```
quote do
  var!(state) = "something"
  unquote(block)
  do_something_else_with(state)
end
```

I know it's evil, but i want to do it just for fun. Is it possible to access that state after that block may or may not have done anything to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but the block and `do_something_else_with` both need to always use `var!(state)` so that macro hygiene doesn't end up giving `state` a different name in the resulting code. Here's an example:

```
defmodule Main do
  defmacro with_state(do: block) do
    quote do
      var!(state) = "something"
      IO.inspect {:before, var!(state)}
      unquote(block)
      IO.inspect {:after, var!(state)}
    end
  end

  def main do
    with_state do
      IO.inspect {:inside_before, var!(state)}
      var!(state) = "else"
      IO.inspect {:inside_after, var!(state)}
    end
  end
end

Main.main
```

Output:

```
{:before, "something"}
{:inside_before, "something"}
{:inside_after, "else"}
{:after, "else"}
```